# Javascript dropdown search

Tags: javascript, html

I have a three tiered dropdown search dependent on each other. Everything works fine but I am looking to put three of them on the same page together. I have renamed each element ID for the three searches but only the third dropdown will search. The first two dropdown searches after clicking on search a "#" comes after the url which I understand why it does but is the a piece of code or anything out there that will allow we to seach the three dropdowns. An example is www.findcarparts.ie of a working search with three on a page.
Below is an example of the code I am dealing with:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var statesx = new Array();
        statesx['Please Select a County'] = new Array('Please Select a County');
        statesx['Antrim'] = new Array('Belfast');
        statesx['Armagh'] = new Array('Armagh');
        statesx['Carlow'] = new Array('Carlow Town');


        // Cityx lists
        var citiesx = new Array();

        citiesx['Please Select a County'] = new Array();
        citiesx['Please Select a County']['Please Select a County'] = new Array('Please Select a County');
        citiesx['Please Select a County']['Please Select a Countylinks'] = new Array('#');

        citiesx['Antrim'] = new Array();
        citiesx['Antrim']['Belfast'] = new Array('Optional', 'Trailer Accessories', 'Winter Products');
        citiesx['Antrim']['Belfastlinks'] = new Array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.ie', 'http://www.google.com');

        citiesx['Armagh'] = new Array();
        citiesx['Armagh']['Armagh'] = new Array('Optional', 'Trailer Accessories', 'Winter Products');
        citiesx['Armagh']['Armaghlinks'] = new Array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.ie', 'http://www.google.com');

        citiesx['Carlow'] = new Array();
        citiesx['Carlow']['Carlow Town'] = new Array('Optional', 'Trailer Accessories', 'Winter Products');
        citiesx['Carlow']['Carlow Townlinks'] = new Array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.ie', 'http://www.google.com');


        function setStatesx() {
            cntrySel = document.getElementById('countyx');
            statexList = statesx[cntrySel.value];
            changeSelect('statex', statexList, statexList);
            setCitiesx();
        }
        function setCitiesx() {
            cntrySel = document.getElementById('countyx');
            statexSel = document.getElementById('statex');
            cityxList = citiesx[cntrySel.value][statexSel.value];
            cityxLinksList = citiesx[cntrySel.value][statexSel.value + "links"];
            changeSelect('cityx', cityxList, cityxLinksList);
        }
        function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
            selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
            selectField.options.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++) {
                selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
            }
        }
        // Multiple onload function created by: Simon Willison
        // http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
        function addLoadEvent(func) {
            var oldonload = window.onload;
            if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
                window.onload = func;
            } else {
                window.onload = function () {
                    if (oldonload) {
                        oldonload();
                    }
                    func();
                }
            }
        }
        addLoadEvent(function () {
            setStatesx();
        });
        function redirect() {
            x = document.getElementById("cityx").value;
            window.location = x;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .make_selection_back {
            background: url('Header_Looking_Image.jpg') no-repeat;
            width: 1160px;
            height: 245px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .make_selection_table {
            position: absolute;
            top: 170px;
            left: 505px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="points-table" class"rounded shadow">
            <form>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="red">County:</font></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="countyx" id="countyx" onchange="setStatesx();">
                                <option value="Please Select a County">Please Select a County</option>
                                <option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
                                <option value="Armagh">Armagh</option>
                                <option value="Carlow">Carlow</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="red">Town:</font></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="statex" id="statex" onchange="setCitiesx();">
                                <option value="">Please select a County</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="red">Manufacturer:</font></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="cityx" id="cityx">
                                <option value="">Please select a County</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="button" name="submit_form" value="Search" onclick="redirect();" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div><!--//make_selection_back-->

    </body>
</html>
```